# How to i configure Feign Client in java spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

**I want to insert data to another database with Feign, and i have error**

This Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceFeignClientConfig {
public ErrorDecoder errorDecoderBeeShop(Decoder decoder) {
    return (String methodKey, Response response) -> {
        try {
            ResponseShop respEnvelope = (ResponseShop) decoder.decode(response, ResponseShop.class);
            MarshallingUtils.printJson(respEnvelope);
            ErrCode errCode = ErrCode.toError(respEnvelope.getMeta().getCode());
            String errMessage = respEnvelope.getMeta().getMessage();
            return new Exception(errCode, errMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Exception(ErrCode.ERR_UNKNOWN, ErrCode.ERR_UNKNOWN.getMessage());
        }
    };
}
```

This Service Feign Client

```
@FeignClient(name = "beeshop-service", url = "http://localhost:9008/", configuration = {ServiceFeignClientConfig.class})
public interface BeeShopServiceClient {

@PutMapping("v1/input-user")
void inputUser(String merchantName, String phoneNumber, String email, Role.ERole roleMerchant);
}
```

And i want to call this endpoint to my Controller

```
beeShopService.updateOrderStatus(merchantName, phoneNumber, email, roleMerchant);
```

And when i run this application i have error

*Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.beepay.service.internal.BeeShopServiceClient': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/Capability*

**How I resolve this? sorry my bad englist**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the @Configuration in the configuration class for feign:

> Configuration does not need to be annotated with @Configuration.
> However, if it is, then take care to exclude it from any
> @ComponentScan that would otherwise include this configuration as it
> will become the default source for feign.Decoder, feign.Encoder,
> feign.Contract, etc., when specified. This can be avoided by putting
> it in a separate, non-overlapping package from any @ComponentScan or
> @SpringBootApplication, or it can be explicitly excluded in
> @ComponentScan.

ref: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Also make sure to enable feign via: @EnableFeignClients in you main config class